# Postgresql drops trailing zeroes when loading time with milliseconds from csv

Tags: postgresql, csv, time, primary-key, trailing

I am importing a csv file into a Postgres Table. The file has the following format:

`2019/12/13, 14:56:02, 3172.50, 3174.25, 3172.50, 3172.50, 1, 1, 1, 0`

The table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
date date,
time time,
v1 numeric,
v2 numeric,
v3 numeric,
v4 numeric,
v5 integer,
v6 integer,
v6 integer,
v7 integer,
PRIMARY KEY(date, time)
);
```

There is an issue with the `time` field. In some cases, milliseconds are added for precision:

```
14:56:02.1
14:56:02.9
14:56:02.10
```

Unfortunately, Postgres seems to drop the trailing zero, which causes it to mark below two values as duplicates:

```
14:56:02.1
14:56:02.10
```

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tablename_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (date, "time")=(2019-12-13, 14:56:02.1) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY input_file, line 1584
```

Is there a way to instruct psql not to drop trailing zeroes? I tried time(4) to enforce 4 digit precision, with no difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres is not doing anything wrong here. It took me a moment to realize that the issue is with the data.

`.1` and `.10` **are** equal. In the data, the timestamp was used creatively, i.e. in this case `.1` means "1st record within this second" and `.10` means "10th record within this second", so the millisecond component didn't make sense from timestamp's point of view.